# Structures are defined using a macro, flycheck gives errors

Tags: flycheck, c, cc-mode, clang

In our source code we surround structures with a macro (MKDIFF) that serves as a flag for the Makefile system. It does not expand into anything, just a flag. Flycheck (understandably) flags these structures as errors.

Here is an example:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
} MKDIFF(node_t);
```

So, in source code when referring to node_t, flycheck flags it as an error (a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition).

Is there a way to have it strip out these macros before parsing structures?

I am using irony server for C/C++ and LLVM/clang syntax checking.